# Why is the MOCK_METHOD syntax not working in GMock?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have not even begun testing and I am encountering some syntax issues with GMock's  MOCK_METHOD macro even though I am following GMock's documentation properly. Could it be a compiler issue? I have:

MingGW (GCC 4.9.2)

Googletest 1.10.x

```
class SimpleClass {

public:
    virtual int simpleFirstFunction(int a, int b) { return (a + simpleSecondFunction(b)); }
    virtual int simpleSecondFunction(int b) { return (2 * b); }
    virtual ~SimpleClass();
};


class MockSimpleClass :public SimpleClass {
    MOCK_METHOD(int, simpleSecondFunction, (int a, int b), (override));
};
```

I am seeing 3 compiler errors:

**Error-1: about the function name**

MockSimpleClass.cpp:18:24: error:

'simpleSecondFunction' is not a type
MOCK_METHOD(int, simpleSecondFunction(int a, int b), (override));

**Error-2: about input parameters**

MockSimpleClass.cpp:18:46: error:

expected identifier before '(' token
       MOCK_METHOD(int, simpleSecondFunction, (int a, int b), (override));

**Error-3: About parentheses around "override"**

MockSimpleClass.cpp:18:60: error:

expected identifier before '(' token
MOCK_METHOD(int, simpleSecondFunction(int a, int b), (override));

Comment: Apart from the answer, notice that you are using `override`, but the number of parametrs is not matching.

Comment: Are you using latest version of google mock ?

Comment: yes. the latest version. but would it matter a lot even if i wasn't? I suppose Google does not abruptly change their basic way of setting mock macros.

Comment: i faced similar issue in visual studio when using google mock from nuget. Solved by using latest version

Answer (score 6):

MOCK_METHOD macro is not defined.
Here is how I troubleshooted the exact same issue:

Check preprocessor: `gcc -E s1.cpp > s1.preproc`.
 First of all check the `gmock.h` included.
 In my case it was:

`72396 # 11 "s1.cpp" 2
72397 # 1 "/usr/include/gmock/gmock.h" 1 3 4`

As you can see a system header is included.
I wen to check googletest version on system(Ubuntu 19.10):

`doliaru@host:~/test/gtest/build$ dpkg -l google*
rc  google-mock:amd64 1.8.1-3      aand using C++ mock classes
ii  googletest:amd64  1.8.1-3      amd64        Google's C++ test frame
dpoliaru@host:~/test/gtest/build$`

Apparently this feature was not implemented in 1.8.
I cloned the most recent version of googletest [here](https://github.com/google/googletest).
Having checked the topmost `CMakeLists.txt` on master branch I see that
current gtest version on master is:
`set(GOOGLETEST_VERSION 1.10.0)`

And I built it with these cmake configs:

`cmake .. -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/dpoliaru/.local/ -D gtest_build_samples=TRUE`

After installation, gmock, that I needed for the project was here:
`/home/dpoliaru/.local/include/gmock/gmock.h`

Thus, I updated `CMakeLists.txt` file of the project with the proper include directory for given target:

`...
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GMOCK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...`

If you are new to cmake, please check their [webpage](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/) and find lots of great stuff in `cmake-data` debian package.

After cmake configure step I see this definition in `flags.cmake` file:

`CXX_INCLUDES = -I/home/dpoliaru/.local/include`

With proper include paths I managed to compile the project.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, according to their release notes, MOCK_METHOD was added only in 1.10
Before it was MOCK_METHOD0/1/2/etc
https://github.com/google/googletest/releases/tag/release-1.10.0

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the MOCK_METHOD macro is not defined. Have you set up your include path correctly and added the `#include "gmock/gmock.h"` directive at the top of your file? You are also missing a `public` access specifier and the number of arguments is wrong for the function.

This should work if you have the gmock headers on your include path:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class SimpleClass {

public:
    virtual int simpleFirstFunction(int a, int b) { return (a + simpleSecondFunction(b)); }
    virtual int simpleSecondFunction(int b) { return (2 * b); }
    virtual ~SimpleClass();
};


class MockSimpleClass : public SimpleClass {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, simpleSecondFunction, (int b), (override));
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my parameter part was wrong. I changed it to int b. But even then, I keep getting the same errors. I included gmock/gmock.h. If MOCK_METHOD was not declared why would it complain about the format of MOCK_METHOD. I suspect there is something going on.

Comment: The compiler will complain if MOCK_METHOD is not defined because MOCK_METHOD will then not be replaced by a valid expression by the preprocessor (which parses and understands macros) before compilation.

I have compiled the example code above successfully with v1.10.0 of googletest. Removing the include of gmock.h gives me the same error you have. If gmock.h is being included, it's possible the header file is from an older version as they only introduced MOCK_METHOD in v1.10.0.